# postfix log difference between to and orig_to

Tags: linux, email, postfix

I have this log entry:

> 2015-01-14T09:26:39.448011+00:00 mx01 postfix/error[29736]:
>   5F8E810015D: to=,
>   orig_to=, relay=none, delay=0.09,
>   delays=0.05/0.03/0/0.01, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (User unknown in
>   virtual alias table)
>
> Jan 14 09:26:39 mx01 postfix/error[29736]: 5F8E810015D: to=, orig_to=, relay=none,
>   delay=0.09, delays=0.05/0.03/0/0.01, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (User
>   unknown in virtual alias table)

what is the difference between to and orig_to in above log? as i am trying to diagnose a bounce back, unable to resolve it.

Answer (score 3):

In most cases, the `orig_to` is for when postfix received a message which is an alias, or a mailing list, or any number of situations where the original `To:` is not the same as where the final delivery ends up. Obviously, this sort of information means that postfix is aware of the redirection.

Comment: thanks, but why is email bouncing back?

Comment: Well, if you take the error at face value, it says that the user (most likely the changed address) is not found. Possibly someone has set up an alias or something similar with a misspelled address?

Comment: The question was anwsered. This fields haven't relation with bounce.